# How to enable the Trace Current Stream Chain

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I wanted to debug a Stream in java .stream().map().  Unfortunately the "Trace Current Stream Chain" button isn't active when I move in the .map() function.

[image]
I have already installed the **Java Stream Debugger** plugin

Any Idea on how to enable it?

Comment: Please check explanation in the related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190907

Comment: @y.bedrov thanks, but this didn't help me solve the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get enable,

1. Enable Java Stream Debugger(File -> Settings -> Plugins)
2. Set a debug Breakpoint on the stream
3. Debug the application

---

When you reach the Breakpoint, the "Trace Current Stream Chain" button will be active.

Comment: I tried following this advice and I cannot enable that plugin in my version of IntelliJ due to a version mismatch. Apparently, this plugin is no longer supported? Leaving this here for future users: 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9696-java-stream-debugger/versions

Comment: @Zap any alternatives?

Comment: That's unfortunate. I get Java Stream Debugger Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1)